# How to make a UITextView call the addTarget method

Tags: ios, uitextview

How will I use the method addTarget with a UITextView?  I know that you can use it with a UITextField, but I can't use it with a UITextView.  I can't even create an action with a UITextView.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UITextView` is not meant to respond to events like that. What functionality are you after?

Comment: I just want to make a `NSString` variable that always has the same text as the `UITextView`'s, so I will need either `addTarget` or `IBAction` for that, right?  And, by the way, the reason I put a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField` is because I wanted this editable field to be multiline.

Comment: Why not just grab the text from the UITextView when needed? `myTextView.text`. If you need events when the user is interacting with the text view, take a look at the delegate. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Comment: Hmm... It still doesn't work.  I mean, it doesn't create an error (like before) or anything like that, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.  I used the `textViewDidChange` method.  Do you think that conforms to my example?

Comment: What events are you trying to use? Do you want to update your local storage variable on key press? Or when a user is done editing?

Comment: I want to update the variable on key press.

Comment: Check the answer below, hopefully that clears it up. I think all you were missing was the delegate :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments, what you'd like to do is update a local variable when the user types in a `UITextView`.

So try something like this (I assume you have a UIViewController subclass, and it's view has the UITextView in questions as a subview):

In your view controller, create an `IBOutlet` to your `UITextView` if using IB, or just a regular reference if not. Then another property for the `NSString` variable you want to store the text into.

NOTE: Make sure this view controller conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol as shown below.

```
@interface BBViewController () <UITextViewDelegate> //Note the protocol here

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userInput;

@end
```

Then, hook up the text view's delegate: (Or do this in IB)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.delegate = self;
}
```

Then when the user interacts with the text in that text view, it will send the proper delegate methods and you can update your variable appropriately.

```
#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    self.userInput = textView.text;
    NSLog(@"userInput %@", self.userInput); //Just an example to show the variable updating
}
```

Comment: Oh man!!!!  The reason why I thought it didn't work was because I didn't put the `self.textView.delegate = self`!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, it's always the easy stuff :)

Comment: That's always the case, isn't it?

Comment: Oh also, I want to do the same thing but with a UIDatePicker.  In other words, what is the "UIControlEventEditingChanged for a UIDatePicker"?

Answer (score 9):

for swift version 3+

1. add `UITextViewDelegate` to your class
2. add delegate to your textview like this :
   `self.mytextview.delegate = self`
3. add this method :

   ```
   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView){ 
       print("entered text:\(textView.text)")    
   }
   ```

Comment: Beware that this is not called when programmatically changing the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using notifications.

```
//Listen to notifications :

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(textView,
            selector: #selector(textDidChange),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange,
            object: nil)

//the function called when changed

    @objc private func textDidChange() {
        ...
    }

//make sure to release to observer as well
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(textView,
            name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange,
            object: nil)
```

Comment: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange doesn't work in Swift 4.2

Comment: Use `UITextView.textDidChangeNotification` in Swift 4.2